# Unable to do fragment to fragment communication

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner, android-spinner

My goal of this is to have two fragments that take up half the screen from top to bottom. The top half should use a fragment to display a spinner. The bottom half should use a fragment to change the background to the selected spinner color from the drop down.

I have an interface made in `PaletteFragment` and implemented it in the `PaletteActivity`. I then created a public variable called `sharedPosition`, which shares the position of the spinner item selected in `PaletteFragment` to `CanvasFragment`. `CanvasFragment` extends `PaletteActivity` so I can receive the `sharedPosition` to adjust the color of the fragment appropriately.

However, once I run the program, the top fragment shows up and displays the spinner just fine, but once I selected a color from the spinner the app crashes. Logcat shows `sharedPoisition` causing it. Im not sure why when the file itself doesnt complain about it.

[image]

This is what my project looks like so far, once I click on a color I want it to change the background of the bottom half of the screen to that color.

**PaletteFragment**:

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import java.util.Locale;



public class PaletteFragment extends Fragment {

    OnColorSelectListener callback;
    public void setOnColorSelectListener(OnColorSelectListener callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    };

    public interface OnColorSelectListener{
        public int onColorSelected(int position);
    }




    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public static PaletteFragment newIntance(){
        return new PaletteFragment();
    }
    public PaletteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment PaletteFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PaletteFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PaletteFragment fragment = new PaletteFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_palette, container, false);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                getActivity(), R.array.myColors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stringNames = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.myStrings, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        stringNames.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stringName = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.myStrings, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        stringName.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_palette,container,false);
        spinner = v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(new ColorAdapter(getActivity()));

        spinner = v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position == 0){
                }
                else if(position == 1){
                    callback.onColorSelected(position);
                }else if(position == 2){
                    callback.onColorSelected(position);
                }else if(position == 3){
                    callback.onColorSelected(position);
                }else if(position == 4){
                    callback.onColorSelected(position);
                }else if(position == 5){
                    callback.onColorSelected(position);
                }else if(position == 6){
                    callback.onColorSelected(position);
                }else if(position == 7){
                    callback.onColorSelected(position);
                }else if(position == 8){
                    callback.onColorSelected(position);
                }else if(position == 9){
                    callback.onColorSelected(position);
                }else if(position == 10){
                    callback.onColorSelected(position);
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
//
}
```

**PaletteActivity**

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import java.util.Locale;


public class PaletteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PaletteFragment.OnColorSelectListener{
    public int sharedPosition;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment){

    }


    public int onColorSelected(int position) {
        sharedPosition = position;
        return position;
    }
}
```

**CanvasFragment**

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import java.util.Locale;


public class CanvasFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        int pos = ((PaletteActivity)getActivity()).sharedPosition;
        String CurrentLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        TextView text = v.findViewById(R.id.newColor);
        final FrameLayout newBackground = v.findViewById(R.id.cfrag_container);


        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        if(pos == 1){

            newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.silver);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 2){
            newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.pink);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 3){
            newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 4){
            newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 5){
            newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 6){
            newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 7){
            newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 8){
            newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.indigo);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 9){
            newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.violet);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 10){
            newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.brown);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(newBackground,pos,text);
            }
        }

        return v;
    }
    private void displayColorName(View newBackground, int pos, TextView text){
        String retrieve[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myStrings);
        String color = retrieve[pos];
        text.setText(color);
    }
}
```

**CanvasActivity**

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CanvasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

}
```

**ColorAdapter**

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ColorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Integer> colors;
    Context context;

    public ColorAdapter(Context context){

        this.context=context;
        colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int retrieve []=context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.myColors);
        for(int i:retrieve)
        {
            colors.add(i);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return colors.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int args) {
        return colors.get(args);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int args) {
        return args;
    }

    public String getElementFromColors(int position){
        String CurrentLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        if(CurrentLang.equals("es")){
            String retrieve[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myStrings);
            return retrieve[position];
        }else{

            String retrieve[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myStrings);
            return retrieve[position];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
        TextView txv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        txv.setBackgroundColor(colors.get(position));
        txv.setText(getElementFromColors(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: A fragment should not extend an activity, that's just defeating the purpose of fragments because they depend on their hosting activity see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60627666/6382534

Comment: Thanks for the heads up fixed the code above. Think I am using the activities global variable the proper way now (dont know if it follows the proper convention though). However, now when I run the program neither fragment is showing up, the screen appears completely blank. Any suggestions?

Comment: The way to achieve what you want is to first add both fragments to the activity layout file as views stacked on top of each other, then add them in the PalleteActivity' onCreate() using the fragmentManager's add() method. Implement the PalleteFragment interface in the PalleteActivity and send info to the CanvasFragment using one of its(the CanvasFragment) instance methods. Remove the CanvasActivity, it would be unnecessary then.